# How to hide add to cart button on single product page - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to wordpress and woocommerce. I've to hide add to cart button if the product weight is greater than 8 grams. I've used this code to do so.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_process', 10, 0 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replace_default_button', 10, 2 );
function replace_default_button( $button, $product ){

$weight = $product->get_weight();
preg_replace('/\D/', '', $weight);

if ( $weight > 8 ){
    $button = '';
}
return $button;
}
```

Its working great on shop page. But its not working on the single product page. Kindly help me to hide the add to cart button in single product page only if the product's weight is greater than 8 grams.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good for the shop page, for the single page you need to use a different hook:

```
// Removing the single product button add to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'replace_single_add_to_cart_button', 1 );
function replace_single_add_to_cart_button() {
    global $product;
    $weight = $product->get_weight();
    preg_replace('/\D/', '', $weight);

    if ( $weight > 8 ){
       // For variable product types
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation','woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button', 20 );
       // For all other product types
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, its working, but I'm using a plugin called 'One Click chat to order' to order the product via whatsapp. After adding this code, It hides this whatsapp button as well.

Comment: Because they plug to the same hook. Try to change the priority, the number at the end of the function remove_action(). If you don't have variable product, delete the first one.

Comment: But I'm not sure at all. I think it will not work, maybe you add manually the button, in the whatsapp plugin, you grab the function they probably have: add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', '...', 30); and you copy that after remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );